# How to write to a specific line in a file

Tags: android, html, filewriter

I have a HTML file and when a user clicks save, a date needs to be added to this html file.

I'm using `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myFile, true);` so it is appended to the end but I have `</body></html>` so the date is appended to the end of this which I don't want. The date should be appended before those tags. Is there a way to append to a specific place or a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You consider redesigning your code in a way that leaved the layout (HTML) appart from the data (the dates).

You could have a HTML containing the fixed string `{{dates_here}}` and store the dates in a database or separate file - and then combine them when needed for viewing by constructing an insertable piece of HTML and inserting it with a simple string replace.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, this is not possible, however, I have a solution. Just leave out the `<body>` and `<html>` tags, and simply append the tags after appending what's needed. Ever so long ago, it's possible to actually omit those two tags. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can keep a DOM in memory of HTML document.

Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) library to make one from a file or String. It will also help you to alter structure in an object oriented way and save it back easily.